# Raphael js get object by id?

Tags: raphael

```
var circle = paper.getById(data.Id);
console.log("circle : " + circle);
circle.attr({ opacity: data.Opacity / 100 });
```

**console output:**

> circle : Raphaël’s object

and

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'attr' of null

I think, first I convert object to circle? How can I change element attribute?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not really clear what your data object is, to know if thats correct, or if the id has been set. Here is an example.. with a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Uvcy9/2/

```
var paper = Raphael('container',200,200);
var newCircle = paper.circle(100,20,20);
newCircle.id='circle1';
paper.add( newCircle );

/// some code here, later we want to reference it...
var circle = paper.getById('circle1');

circle.attr({ fill: 'red', opacity: circle.attr('opacity') / 10 });
```